# Detalle en la función quicksort en C

Tags: c

Estoy implementando un pequeño programa que lea datos separados por una coma, la función `qsort( )` me funciona, pero tiene un pequeño error. Este es el código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
    char name[101];
    unsigned short age;
    float score;
}player;

// --------------------Prototypes--------------------
void input( player *, unsigned short );
int compareScore( const void * , const void * );

// ---------------------------Main Program------------------------
int main(void)
{
    player listOfPlayers[10000];
    unsigned short total, i;

    scanf("%hu\n", &total);

    input(listOfPlayers, total);

    qsort(listOfPlayers, total, sizeof(player), compareScore);

    printf("\nORDER BY SCORE\n");
    printf("==============\n");

    for ( i = 0 ; i < total ; i ++ )
        printf("%s %hu %.1f\n", listOfPlayers[i].name, listOfPlayers[i].age, listOfPlayers[i].score);


    return 0;
}


//------------------------------Functions----------------------------------
void input( player *list, unsigned short total)
{
    unsigned short i;
    for ( i = 0 ; i < total ; i ++ )
    {
        scanf("%100[^,]s", list[i].name);
        getchar();
        scanf("%hu", &list[i].age);
        getchar();
        scanf("%f", &list[i].score);
        getchar();
    }

    for ( i = 0 ; i < total ; i ++ )
        printf("%s %hu %.1f\n", list[i].name, list[i].age, list[i].score);

}

int compareScore( const void *pivot , const void *element )
{
    player *ptrPivot = ( player * ) pivot;
    player *ptrElement = ( player * ) element;

    return (ptrElement -> score) - (ptrPivot -> score);
}
```

En este programa leo el nombre, edad y puntaje de un jugador y tengo que ordenar los datos de mayor a menor,según su puntaje y mostrarlos por pantalla. Este es un ejemplo:

Input:

```
5
MARIO,25,6
RODRIGO,20,7
ALEJANDRA,21,5.5
SAMUEL,69,2.8
fernando,69,4.5
```

Output:

> ORDER BY SCORE
>   
>   RODRIGO 20 7.0
>   MARIO 25 6.0
>   ALEJANDRA 21 5.5
>   fernando 69 4.5
>   SAMUEL 69 2.8

El código resuelve este ejemplo perfectamente, pero al momento de cambiar los datos de entrada: 
Input:

```
5
MARIO,25,6.8
RODRIGO,20,7
ALEJANDRA,21,5.5
SAMUEL,69,5.6
fernando,69,8
```

output:

> ORDER BY SCORE
>   
>   fernando 69 8.0
>   MARIO 25 6.8
>   RODRIGO 20 7.0
>   ALEJANDRA 21 5.5
>   SAMUEL 69 5.6

El código marca errores. Si los puntajes, que están en float, tienen decimales de diferencia marca los errores. La salida esperada del ejemplo anterior es:

Output **esperado**:

> ORDER BY SCORE
>   
>   fernando 69 8.0
>   RODRIGO 20 7.0
>   MARIO 25 6.8
>   SAMUEL 69 5.6
>   ALEJANDRA 21 5.5

Answer (score 0):

La solución es cambiar la línea

```
return (ptrElement -> score) - (ptrPivot -> score);
```

por

```
return (ptrElement -> score > ptrPivot -> score) - (ptrElement -> score < ptrPivot -> score);
```

Extraído de: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3886446/problem-trying-to-use-the-c-qsort-function

Yo tampoco encontraba el error a simple vista, lo verifiqué con tu lote de pruebas.
Saludos.